# What is the best way to get date and time in Clojure?

Tags: java, datetime, clojure

I need to log some events on a Clojure Client-Server scenario, but it seems to me that Clojure does not provide a date/time function. Can any one confirm this or I am missing something here?! If I am correct then I need to use java interop, right?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If all you need is to get the current time and date for your logger, then this function is OK:

```
 (defn now [] (new java.util.Date))
```

Now that you mentioned this, it would be useful to have support for immutable Date objects.

Comment: Great, I think I'd go with (print (.getTime (now))) to preserve reasonable precision in my log files. Thanks.

Comment: `(defn now [] (java.util.Date.))` is the canonical version.

Answer (score 40):

Java 1.8 added the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package to the core JDK to clean up many of the [frustrations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) with the state of date & time in Java.  Since java.time is now a widely available part of core Java with a much improved API, I would encourage you to give it the first look when writing new date & time code.

Here's how you can retrieve the current date and time:

```
(java.time.LocalDateTime/now)
```

Comment: => (.toString (java.time.LocalDateTime/now))
;; =>   "2021-03-23T16:23:14.679916"

This is something I felt useful

Answer (score 19):

There is a [Clojure-wrapper library for Joda-Time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time).  Or you'll have to use java interop with the standard Java API.

Comment: Thanks, but I rather keep my dependencies as low as possible.

Comment: @Ali - a sane date-time library is a dependency you should seriously consider; unfortunately the standard libraries (for a lot of languages) aren't always sufficiently precise.

Answer (score 13):

With [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time), the Clojure library that wraps the Java Joda Time library, you could use code like the following:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as time])
(require '[clj-time.format :as time-format])

(time/now) => #<DateTime 2013-03-31T03:23:47.328Z>

(def time-formatter (time-format/formatters :basic-date-time))  ;; ISO 8601 UTC format
(time-format/unparse custom-formatter (date-time 2010 10 3)) => "20101003T000000.000Z"
```

One benefit of Joda Time (and hence clj-time) is that new releases support new changes to time zones.

Comment: this library is now deprecated

Comment: @Agata I'm not using Clojure (or Java) currently, and haven't for a few years now, but I _think_ that's because Joda Time is deprecated too, and because its features were finally incorporated into Java itself (IIRC).

Answer (score 13):

If you dont need nothing more advanced, just use Java classes.

`(.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "MM/dd/yyyy") (new java.util.Date))`

Answer (score 0):

`java.time` is available in Java 8 onward and is a relatively straight forward approach to creating a time stamp for logs

`java.time` namespace is included in Clojure by default, so available without the need for a `require expression.

```clj
(java.time.LocalDate/now)
```

Evaluating this expression returns a Java Time object which should work with most log frameworks

```
#object[java.time.LocalDate 0x5814b4fb "2023-07-13"]
```

For example, in [mulog](https://github.com/BrunoBonacci/mulog) the following event log includes a date-time stamp

```clj
(ns practicalli.gameboard.system
  "Service component lifecycle management"
  (:gen-class)
  (:require
   [com.brunobonacci.mulog :as mulog]))

(mulog/log 
  ::log-publish-component
  :local-time (java.time.LocalDateTime/now))
```

> NOTE: change the namespace to match the file name or add a suitable require to your namespace and copy the mulog/log expression